# Is a serviced component shared between user sessions on a terminal server, or is one process started for each user session?

Tags: windows, .net-4.5, com+, terminal-services

I have some .NET code in a COM+/Enterprise Services serviced component. I communicate with this component from a WPF application and also from a legacy VBA application.

This arrangement works well when only one user is logged on to a machine. The component starts in its own process when either the .NET or the legacy application instantiates one of its COM objects.

The system also works for the *first user* to try to run it on a terminal server installation. However, when another user logs on, he/she is unable to use the application. I had hoped that each session would run in isolation, and that one host process would run per session. Am I wrong in this expectation?

In Component Services on the **Activation** tab my application is configured to run as a "Server application". On the **Identity** tab, "Interactive user" is selected. On the **Security** tab, "Enforce access checks for this application" is unchecked.

Comment: Some further research... according to [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686587(v=vs.85).aspx), "If the identity is set to be the interactive user, all clients use the same instance of the server if the server registers its class factory as multi-use."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to find anything authoritative on this. For standard COM you can [set the identity to 'Launching user'](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms693789(v=vs.85).aspx). The same is not available for COM+.

According to [this archived post](http://marc.info/?l=ms-dcom&m=103440699422225&w=2),

> A COM+ application can be configured to run under the logged in account, or
>   a specified account. Under the application properties, see the Identity tab.
>   ...
>   Once set however, it remains under that account until the application shuts
>   down, so you can't have multiple users using the same COM+ application under
>   different IDs.

That seems to match what is said in [this knowledge base article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/305761/en-gb) too.

My conclusion is, I should probably accept that my component **must run once per machine** rather than once per session. It will need to be modified to accommodate this. Since it needs to start new processes in individual sessions, it will have to run as a **Windows service** under the **Local System** account (giving due attention to the security implications).

Answer (score 0):

There isn't session isolation as you describe, instead process ownership limits what you have access to.
Your conclusion seems correct & you will need to determine a suitable mechanism to exchange data with the service.

I used WCF to create a service with a net named pipe listener https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/index

The idea of using proxies to make rpc calls is attractive, but I found the proxy definitions and stubs to link it all together quite clumsy to use.

If you have events that may be triggered at either end then keeping client/service in sync becomes problematic.

AIUI you cannot invoke a rpc method that ends up invoking an rpc back at the originating end, although that could be a named pipe limitation.

If I was doing this again I would use a socket server in the service & the websocket protocol for biderectional data transfer, even though you might need to implement some thread handling to avoid the listener thread blocking whilst servicing requests.